# ¿Dónde inserto Jquery en un JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Mi problema es que tengo mi código JavaScript al cual quiero añadirle Jquery para una función de botones dinámicos, el problema es que no sé que etiquetas debo usar para activar el Jquery.

Básicamente lo que quiero hacer es que al seleccionar el "concatenar" me muestre el botón unir y que al seleccionar "Borrar" me muestre el botón borrar(este aún no le he añadido función) añadido a eso, que al seleccionar "concatenar" se oculte el botón de borrar y que al presionar "Borrar" me muestre el botón para borrar.

Pd: El botón limpiar no es lo mismo que el de borrar.
Este es mi código JavaScript con base en HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Unir con salto de linea</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div name="head" class="h">
<table>
<tr>
<form name="prueba" autocomplete="off">
   <td><strong>Primera Frase: <input type="text"id="textA" /></td></strong>
   <td><strong>Frase final: <input type="text"id="textB" /></td></strong>
<td><select id="sel" required>
  <option value="concatenar">Concatenar</option>
  <option value="borrar">Borrar</option>
</select></td>
 </table>
</form>
</div>
</tr>
<script>
function unirTexto(){
var c1=document.getElementById('textA').value;
var c2=document.getElementById('textB').value;
var t1=document.getElementById('textC').value;
var rt=document.getElementById('resultado');
  var copia=  document.getElementById('copia');
  var p = t1.split(/\n/g);
  var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
  var html = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {html += c1 +' '+ p[i] +' '+ c2 + "\n"; copia.innerHTML = html; }}
function limpiar() {
document.getElementById('textA').value ="";
document.getElementById('textB').value ="";
document.getElementById('textC').value ="";
document.getElementById('copia').innerHTML ="";
}
</script>
<div name="botons" class="b"><table><tr><td><button onclick="unirTexto()" id="unir">Unir</button>
<button id="borrar">Borrar</button>
<button onclick="limpiar()" id="limpiar">Limpiar</button></td></tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td><strong>Contenido Medio</strong></td>
<td><strong>Resultado</strong></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td><textarea name="textC" id="textC" cols="91" rows="33"></textarea></td>
<td><textarea id="copia" type="text" cols="91" rows="33" placeholder="El resultado se mostrará acá"></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Y este es el fragmento de código que no sé en dónde debo colocarlo:

```js
$('#sel').on('change', function() {
    $('#' + $(this).val()).prop('disabled', false)
      .siblings().prop('disabled', true);
});

$('#sel').on('change', function() {
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show()
      .siblings().hide();
});
```

Comment: Tienes un error conceptual colega.. cabe mencionar que `Javascript` y `JQuery` son prácticamente lo mismo, con la diferencia que JQuery es un conjunto de librerías Javascript que ayudan a simplificar el desarrollo. Para utilizar JQuery sólo debes importarlo a tu proyecto.. te dejo el **[link](http://w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)** para que comiences a utilizarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es agregar la librería de jquery. Despues de agregar la libreróa puedes agregar el fragmento de código dentro de tu etiqueta `<script>`. Adicional a eso agregué una función al evento ready, que se ejecuta cuando el DOM ha sido cargado, esto para mostrar u ocultar los botones correspondientes de acuerdo al valor seleccionado del select en primera instancia, eso se hace mediante el siguiente código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 if($(sel).val() == "borrar") {
  $('#borrar').show();
  $('#unir').hide();
 } else if($(sel).val() == "concatenar") {
  $('#borrar').hide();
  $('#unir').show();
 }
});
```

Y para la funcionalidad que deseas, de acuerdo al valor seleccionado se muestren u oculten los botones:

```
$('#sel').on('change', function() {
 if($(this).val() == "borrar") {
  $('#borrar').show();
  $('#unir').hide();
 } else if($(this).val() == "concatenar") {
  $('#borrar').hide();
  $('#unir').show();
 }
});
```

El código completo sería:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Unir con salto de linea</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div name="head" class="h">
<table>
<tr>
<form name="prueba" autocomplete="off">
   <td><strong>Primera Frase: <input type="text"id="textA" /></td></strong>
   <td><strong>Frase final: <input type="text"id="textB" /></td></strong>
<td><select id="sel" required>
  <option value="concatenar">Concatenar</option>
  <option value="borrar">Borrar</option>
</select></td>
 </table>
</form>
</div>
</tr>
<script>
function unirTexto(){
var c1=document.getElementById('textA').value;
var c2=document.getElementById('textB').value;
var t1=document.getElementById('textC').value;
var rt=document.getElementById('resultado');
  var copia=  document.getElementById('copia');
  var p = t1.split(/\n/g);
  var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
  var html = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {html += c1 +' '+ p[i] +' '+ c2 + "\n"; copia.innerHTML = html; }}
function limpiar() {
document.getElementById('textA').value ="";
document.getElementById('textB').value ="";
document.getElementById('textC').value ="";
document.getElementById('copia').innerHTML ="";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 if($(sel).val() == "borrar") {
  $('#borrar').show();
  $('#unir').hide();
 } else if($(sel).val() == "concatenar") {
  $('#borrar').hide();
  $('#unir').show();
 }
});

$('#sel').on('change', function() {
 if($(this).val() == "borrar") {
  $('#borrar').show();
  $('#unir').hide();
 } else if($(this).val() == "concatenar") {
  $('#borrar').hide();
  $('#unir').show();
 }
});


</script>
<div name="botons" class="b"><table><tr><td><button onclick="unirTexto()" id="unir">Unir</button>
<button id="borrar">Borrar</button>
<button onclick="limpiar()" id="limpiar">Limpiar</button></td></tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td><strong>Contenido Medio</strong></td>
<td><strong>Resultado</strong></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td><textarea name="textC" id="textC" cols="91" rows="33"></textarea></td>
<td><textarea id="copia" type="text" cols="91" rows="33" placeholder="El resultado se mostrará acá"></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Solucionaste todos mis problemas, realmente te agrdezco.

Answer (score 1):

Solo añade la libreria de **Jquery** dentro de tu etiqueta `<head>` así:

```
<head>
  <title>Unir con salto de linea</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

ó al final antes de terminar la etiquta `<body>` así:

```
    </table>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Lugo ya puedes incluir tu código **Jquery** dentro de tus etiquetas `<script>` así:

```
<script>
function unirTexto(){
  var c1=document.getElementById('textA').value;
  var c2=document.getElementById('textB').value;
  var t1=document.getElementById('textC').value;
  var rt=document.getElementById('resultado');
  var copia=  document.getElementById('copia');
  var p = t1.split(/\n/g);
  var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
  var html = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {html += c1 +' '+ p[i] +' '+ c2 + "\n"; copia.innerHTML = html; }}
function limpiar() {
document.getElementById('textA').value ="";
document.getElementById('textB').value ="";
document.getElementById('textC').value ="";
document.getElementById('copia').innerHTML ="";
}

$('#sel').on('change', function() {
    $('#' + $(this).val()).prop('disabled', false)
      .siblings().prop('disabled', true);
});

$('#sel').on('change', function() {
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show()
      .siblings().hide();
});

</script>
```

Comment: Una explicación bastante específica, gracias.

Comment: no es una buena idea cargar librerías o archivos con código JS al inicio del documento HTML, pues al momento de acceder al sitio web bloquearán o ralentizarán al mismo si deben leer etiquetas del DOM, además de eso si ya esta usando JQuery no debería usar innerHTML, ya que existe un método en dicha librería como html()